# QGIS forgotten master password - deleted database - now having trouble getting layer configurations to work

Tags: qgis, authentication

Returning to a project after several years away from QGIS and I found that the master password in 1password does not work.  I deleted the auth database when prompted after 3 failed attempts and restarted QGID (3.24).

I was prompted for the Postgres user and password for each layer and got the project loaded but I can't figure out how to actually set up a new configuration in the auth db and the get the layers to use it.

The layers use an authcfg
[image]

I have defined an authcfg with the same name

[image]

but I still get prompted for the creds for each layer when I restart after using the master config to authenticate.

I then tried cancelling each layer auth until I got the table with layers that could not be loaded and used the edit button to reset the authcfg for the layer from the dropdown menu.  The displayed authcfg changed to a UID (hex string).

quit QGIS and restarted -- it still prompted for each layer.

Lastly I repeated the process and did a `save as` with a new project name.  That did not work either

I have r'ed the f (fine ;) manual section 24 to get this far bug I am clearly missing something.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: I wonder if this is a MacOS issue involving saving changes in the project.  I found several things that looked like they should work but didn't.

For instance canceling all the failed auth dialogues and the when the list of missing layers was presented clicking edit on each layer and setting the correct authcfg.  This worked for the session but when one saved the project and reopened it the problem was still there.

ditto for using the `Data Source Manager`.

This worked:

Before you start make backup copies of any files you intend to edit!

1. create a new authentication data base `settings/preferences => authentication`
2. add a new entry with a different name to the one used in the lost db
3. edit the project file and replaced all the `authcfg=` entries with the name of the new  entry created in step 2

Beware using search and replace!  I found that some of the entries did not have the name in the layer entry.  Instead it had the id #.  So I ended up searching through the file for `authcfg=` and fixing the numeric entries. This was confusing because it caused the authentication failed dialogue and I at first thought the the method had failed.